# Foundation Zurb Grid Content Stacking

Tags: html, css

I am new to Foundation by Zurb, and I am having to use it for a client. Now I've encountered something unexpected with the overlapping of my content.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns">
        <p>osidjsaoidusaoidjsaodisjdoisjdosaidjsaoidjsaoidjsaoidjsaoidjsaodijsodijsaodijsaoidjasoidjsaodijsadoijsadoijsdoisajdosaidjfgdpf</p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns">
        <p>osidjsaoidusaoidjsaodisjdoisjdosaidjsaoidjsaoidjsaoidjsaoidjsaodijsodijsaodijsaoidjasoidjsaodijsadoijsadoijsdoisajdosaidjfgdpf</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

This gives an unexpected content overlap that looks like the following:

[a busy cat http://mdixon94.co.uk/issue.png](http://mdixon94.co.uk/issue.png)

Simply I'm sure through previous grid systems that content is meant to divide into two separate columns. Is their something I'm missing? I've attempted clearfixes.

I am referring to the text that is overlapping in the bottom part of the image and the fact that it overlaps out of the grid.

Comment: Your image is not working

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that there are not any blank space in text that you entered in `<p>` tag. If you put in real content inside '.columns', like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="kitten.jpg" alt="kitten"/>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="kitten.jpg" alt="kitten"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

it will align properly.

Also you can delete this classes from columns "medium-6 large-6" since foundation is mobile first framework, you can just define "small-6" column and this rule will be applied for other breakpoints.

Here is the fiddle:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvQ8d/3/)